# CC text and attribution is hard to see on new footer

Tags: bug, design

[image]

Of course it shows up better in the picture...  But on the actual site the white letters are hard to see specifically because the background picture gets lighter though that area.

Not major but it was annoying the first time I looked at it and had to get close to my monitor to see it.

Ironically enough, on this site (meta) the black on grey of the beach scene is much easier to read. However you can't tell that [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and [attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), are links.

Comment: I had trouble reading it too.